# Can Rainbow Servant be combined with Versatile Spellcaster and Spontaneous Divination to cast all Cleric spells spontaneously?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, wizard, prestige-class

A ridiculous idea has occurred to me and I'm looking to verify if really works. Consider the following build:

- Wizard 5/Rainbow Servant 10 (a class from *Complete Divine*)
- At Wizard 5, take Spontaneous Divination from *Complete Champion* so that you qualify for Versatile Spellcaster from *Races of the Dragon*.
- Take Versatile Spellcaster at some point.
- At Rainbow Servant 10, you gain access to the entire Cleric spell list.
- Put together, Versatile Spellcaster and Rainbow Servant 10 should let a Wizard cast spontaneously from the entire Cleric spell list.

This gives me two questions, the first as a focus and the second as a supplemental:

1. Does this actually work? My first objection is that I'm not quite sure if the Wizard automatically knows all of the Cleric spells at Rainbow Servant 10. If you have to record them in your spellbook, you'll soon run out of gold.
2. If this does work, can the "powerful non-Diviner spellcaster class that can also cast spontaneously from the entire Cleric spell list" idea be done better? The term "Rainbow Warake" seems to be in my memory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this does not work:

> A 10th-level rainbow servant can learn and cast spells from the cleric list,

This grants the ability to learn the spells, but does not automatically have you learn them. The wizard still needs to scribe them in their spellbook, and a sorcerer would need to learn them, and so on. Spontaneous divination and Versatile Spellcaster both specify you need to know the spell you want, so those don’t change the equation.

The “full list” spellcasters, beguiler, dread necromancer, and warmage, are often claimed to be exceptions here, and that these classes really do get to spontaneously cast off of the entire cleric spell list. There are problems with that, however—see our [dedicated Q&A on the subject](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/203478/4563).

Answer (score 2):

### Theoretically yes if you spend time and gold, up your DM

Step by step :

- *Spontaneous Divination* has been errata-ed by WotC :
  The first sentence should instead read, “You can spontaneously cast any spell you know
  from the divination school by sacrificing a prepared spell of equal or greater level.”
  You have to know the spell to cast it, but will give you the Spontaneous casting
  feature required for the next step.
- *Versatile Spellcasting* allows you to fuel a spell you know of a certain level with two spell slots one level lower. This should work, by sacrificing two spell slots of a lower rank and chaining with *Spontaneous Divination*.
- Rainbow Servant 10 allows you to expand the list of available spells you can choose
  from when you add spells to your spellbook. You do not automatically add them to your
  spellbook so yes, it could end costing a lot of gold (even if using *Boccob's Blessed
  Book*). **You were right in you 1st point**.

You end up burning two spells slots to cast one of a higher level you know. To me, that's a slightly better version of *Versatile Spellcasting* as it would work for Wizard, and that would work.

You are now a sorcerer, with one caster level increase due to the fact of being a wizard, with full access to cleric spells and the learning capabilities of a wizard.
That's better than a Sorcerer 5 / Rainbow Servant 10 with Versatile Spellcasting.

As a DM, unsure if I would allow this :)

I will let your second point to other answers, but Ur-Priest quickly comes to mind.

Hoping that helps !

Comment: Officially, rainbow servant does not lose spellcasting at any level—the rules state that text is primary and tables are secondary, and the text of rainbow servant says it gains spellcasting progression at each level, no exceptions. _Complete Divine_ has errata, and has been reprinted several times, and this has never been corrected or commented upon officially.

Comment: Noted, but in fact I was comparing a Wizard 5 / Rainbow Servant 10 to a Sorc 15. I edited my conclusion to compare what is comparable, Sorc 5 / Rainbow Servant 10.

Comment: Also, I feel that “yes” is incorrect—wizard **cannot** cast off of the entire cleric spell list without scribing them all into a spellbook, which was part of what was being asked after. The big “yes” is thus misleading, I think.